# ActiveAdmin index as table and avoiding HTML escaping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I've got this Index as Table set up, and in one of the columns I wish to display multiple rows of short text strings for each row. If I simply add line breaks 
 they are escaped and shown verbatim in the column.

Is there any way to avoid the escaping of the HTML in these columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems all I had to do was call raw with the desired output:

```
raw("your string here,<br>now without escaping the html")
```

Answer (score 0):

`"aaa<br>bbb<br>ccc".html_safe` works for me